# Which function is being called using an array destructuring assigment?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

```js
let [x, y] = ["Ele", "Stack"].reduce((a, s) => {
  a.x = s;
  a.y = s;
  return a;
}, { x: {}, y: {}});
```

The code snippet above throws an error because is trying to make an array destructuring assignment over an object (key:value).

**I have a lack of knowledge**

Which function is being called using an array destructuring assignment?

Comment: The ```reduce``` is returning an object. So you have to do ```{x, y}``` instead of ```[x, y]```

Comment: Yes, I know that.  The question is regarding the array destructuring assignment error.

Comment: What do you mean by function? There is no function being called by a destructuring assignment.

Comment: Well, I think a function is being called because the js engine is trying to call a function as you can see the error.

Comment: What are you expecting as output? Could you please explain?

Comment: I don’t want any output, I want to understand the internal behavior of an array destructuring assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting that type error because array destructuring implicitly calls `Array[Symbol.iterator]`, which is undefined since you're actually returning an object, not an array, from `reduce()`. The fix is to replace it with Object destructuring

```js
let {x, y} = ["Ele", "Stack"].reduce((a, s) => {
  a.x = s;
  a.y = s;
  return a;
}, { x: {}, y: {}});
console.log({ x, y })
```

Comment: Umm probably that’s the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The `array` destructuring works like it's taking the index of the array and put it into the variables you assigned.

For example, say the array is-

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Now you want to destructure the array elements into variables.

```
const [a, b] = arr;
```

This will put the value off `arr[0]` into `a` and `arr[1]` into `b`. This way you can assign as many as you want.

If you want to put two indexes into two variables and rest of the elements into another array you do it by using spreading operator like this-

```
const [a, b, ...rest] = arr;
```

Here, `a` takes the value of `arr[0]` and `b` takes the element of `arr[1]` and `rest` takes the rest of the elements into `rest` array. So the `rest` array would be-

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I know all what you’ve explained, the question is addressed to a behavioral problem when we are trying to destructure an object using the array destructuring assignment approach.